# How to monitor multiple USB UPS with Network UPS Tools

Tags: raspberry-pi, nut

I'm currently running [NUT](https://networkupstools.org/docs/user-manual.chunked/index.html) on my RaspberryPi (using [Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/)), I have managed to connect my [Mecer](https://mecer.co.za/category/products/accessories/ups/) USB UPS to NUT using the blazer_USB driver.

Recently I got another UPS (same model) and would like to connect it to the same Pi via USB.

The second UPS is connected and configured but the Pi only reads one UPS. When both UPS are connected it reads UPS2; if i remove the USB cable of UPS2 it then reads UPS1.

/etc/nut/ups.conf

```
[upswifi]
    driver = blazer_usb
    port = /dev/usb
    desc = "Dearx_UPS_WIFI_1"

[upslan]
    driver = blazer_usb
    port = /dev/usb
    desc = "Dearx_UPS_LAN"
```

LSUSB output

```
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0665:5161 Cypress Semiconductor USB to Serial
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0665:5161 Cypress Semiconductor USB to Serial
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0424:7800 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I think it only sees 1 USB connection at a time, Is there a way i can monitor both via usb on the same system?

Comment: [1]: https://networkupstools.org/docs/user-manual.chunked/ar01s02.html#_drivers  
  [2]: https://networkupstools.org/docs/user-manual.chunked/ar01s06.html#_basic_configuration  
  [3]: https://networkupstools.org/docs/man/blazer_usb.html  
  [4]: https://networkupstools.org/docs/man/nut-scanner.html

Comment: [NUT's manual][1] shows it supports multiple simultaneous UPS. But you are using the same port to look at both; 'port = /dev/usb' is used for both device configs. The [manual][2] also says "If you own more than one, refer to the driver’s manual page][3] for more info on matching a specific device." I looked there &  found you need to add 'bus=001' to each config. Since you only have 1 USB bus (do you? Please check), you must find how to address devices 008 & 009. Look at [nutscanner][4]. ((Links above.)) Would you please run it & post the results by clicking [edit] & add them to your question?

Comment: Hey there, Thanks for the response. NUT dos not have nut-scanner for Raspberry pi Raspbian. I have both UPSs connected to the PI each using its own cable and in its own USB port. I know the ports are the same, the only reason for this is because i cant Find the second USB port in the Dev dir. Let me play around and give some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Use **lsusb -v** to get a more detailed view of the usb connections.  For each Mercer you should see a serial number.  If so, add that serial number to your ups.conf config.  Below is my config for two CyberPower UPS units that are the same model:

```
[cyberpower-c]
  driver = usbhid-ups
  port = auto
  desc = "CyberPower CST135XLU - Back Porch: Computer"
  vendorid = 0764
  productid = 0501
  serial = CR7H****
[cyberpower-f]
  driver = usbhid-ups
  port = auto
  desc = "CyberPower CST135XLU - Back Porch: Router"
  vendorid = 0764
  productid = 0501
  serial = CR7D****
```

This should solve your problem.